# fastlane slather action fails to install gem

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, fastlane

Using MacOSX 10.12.4, ran the fastlane slather action for first time today. When fastlane tries to install the gem it fails. Looking at the mkmf.log, referred to in the fastlane error it generates, it shows this when building nokogiri:

```
In file included from conftest.c:1:
In file included from /Users/mstoner/.fastlane/bin/bundle/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33:
In file included from /Users/mstoner/.fastlane/bin/bundle/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:29:
/Users/mstoner/.fastlane/bin/bundle/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/defines.h:26:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
^
1 error generated.
```

Appears that it can't find stdio.h when building the nokogiri gem dependency. I am able to use the system slather gem ("install gem slather") from non-fastlane scripts perfectly fine. I have already installed the XCode command line tools, rebooted and tried running the fastlane command as sudo, none of which got around the error. Where should nokogiri be looking for stdio.h?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you are using the prepackaged (contained, brew) version of fastlane, this however has known issues with gem dependencies that require native ruby extensions.  there is an ongoing investigation on how to fix it (here: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/8431#issuecomment-284428794)

as this is not yet fixed/release, you could install fastlane via `gem` (best using `rvm/rbenv`)

please see: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane#installation (for additional setup methods)

Comment: Thanks @Helmut-Januschka, that's exactly what I ended up having to do - use the straight rubygem version of fastlane using rvm to keep things clea. That got around the slather gem issue